# angular template enum is undefined in controller function

Tags: angular

I have the following in my angular(4) app:

```
export enum RegisterAccomodationStatus {
    noFixedAbode = 1,
    sofaSurfing = 2,
    accommodation = 3,
    other = 4
}
```

Within my template I have:

```
<button (click)="setCurrentAccomStatus(attendance, registerAccomodationStatus.noFixedAbode)" type="button" class="btn btn-default">NFA</button>
<button (click)="setCurrentAccomStatus(attendance, registerAccomodationStatus.sofaSurfing)" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Sofa</button>
```

I set a property in my component:

```
registerAccomodationStatus: RegisterAccomodationStatus = RegisterAccomodationStatus.other;
```

And then finally my function:

```
setCurrentAccomStatus(registerAttendance: RegisterAttendance, accomStatusId: RegisterAccomodationStatus) {
        console.log(accomStatusId);
        registerAttendance.accomodationStatus = accomStatusId;

        this.registerService.updateGuestAttendance(registerAttendance)
            .subscribe(registerAtt => registerAttendance = registerAtt);
    }
```

When clicking one of the buttons `console.log(accomStatusId);` is giving `undefined` but I'm following the examples I've found on the net to do this.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: yurzui I get ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'noFixedAbode' of undefined

Comment: Try RegisterAccomodationStatus.noFixedAbode

Comment: @Simon  What do you expect in the logs?

Comment: Roman C one of  noFixedAbode = 1,
    sofaSurfing = 2,
    accommodation = 3,
    other = 4

Comment: yurzui that is odd, is that using 2 or 4?

Comment: I used such things in 2 while my plunker uses v4.0.1. So it should work everywhere

Comment: Hang on. I copied and pasted your answer and it worked yurzui. Do you want to add it as an answer below so I can mark as correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should define property like:

```
registerAccomodationStatus = RegisterAccomodationStatus;
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/wRWb0Fc3iELzQbtvkrUC?p=preview)**