# Using enums in Angular2 view templates

Tags: angular, angular2-template

Interesting question. I need to use Angualar4 templating with enums.

Aka.

```
<div class="small-12 columns compliance-freq__item"
             [ngClass]="getComplianceFrequencyClasses( complianceFrequency, LicenceComplianceFrequency.QUARTERLY)"</div>
```

Notice the

LicenceComplianceFrequency.QUARTERLY

enum declaration as follows

```
export enum LicenceComplianceFrequency {
    QUARTERLY               = "QUARTERLY",
    MONTHLY                 = "MONTHLY"
}
```

This gives me a template error,

Cannot read property QUARTERLY of undefined.

I have tried intergrating this with the template in many ways, by modifiying the component itself.

1) still QUARTERLY of undefined error in the template

```
get LicenceComplianceFrequency() {
    return LicenceComplianceFrequency;
}
```

2) (screams that LicenceComplianceFrequency is not an exportable element of file *.ts)

```
import {LicenceComplianceFrequency} from '....';
public LicenceComplianceFrequency = LicenceComplianceFrequency;
```

Any advice?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43126875/angular-template-enum-is-undefined-in-controller-function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry, I already found the answer myself.

The following works with the template. Its not nice that I have to declare it this way and not be able to use enums globally, but of well...

Put this code in the component

```
import * as LicenceComplianceFrequency from '...';
public LicenceComplianceFrequency = LicenceComplianceFrequency;
```

And then you can use it in the template as follows

```
<div class="compliance__item">{{ LicenceComplianceFrequency.QUARTERLY }}</div>
```

## Edit

In newer Angular versions, it is possible to do it like this

```
import {LicenceComplianceFrequency} from "../../shared/enums/licence-compliance-frequency.enum";
public LicenceComplianceFrequency = LicenceComplianceFrequency;
```

Using it in templates remains the same as before

```
<div class="compliance__item">{{ LicenceComplianceFrequency.QUARTERLY }}</div>
```

Comment: Hi, even though you answered your own question, you should still mark it as an answer if it solved your problem.If it works it works and others should be able to see that this solved the issue in question at a first glance.

Comment: Thanks. Marked it as an answer.